# Clone key from void pointer

Tags: c

I'm working on a school excerise.

I'm building a hash table, I'm required to copy a key, when the only thing I get is a void pointer to the key, I need to allocate memory for him, clone him and and return the cloned void pointer.

Now im having a hard time to understand how is it possible to clone him with out knowning his type in order to save enough space?

The brief given from the school staff:

- @brief Allocate memory for an object which contain duplication of the given key.
- If run out of memory, free all the memory that was already allocated by the function `typedef void * (*CloneKeyFcn)(const void * key)`

Comment: Well, you always have the key size. :)

Comment: won't the key size change if the key is an int , or a string?

Comment: What is the key in your case? If the key it's an `int` or some other simple type then it's `sizeof int`, or `sizeof whatever`, if it's a string, then it's `strlen((const char*)key);`. You need to be more explicit.

Comment: BTW if you don't know what kind of data your void pointer is pointing to, you're out of luck. There is no way to find out, you need to know.

Comment: I understand , then it is impossible to build this function with out knowning with type is the key?

Comment: @DavidPitts yes, but you probably didn't tell us everything. The brief you write on your question is incomplete.

Comment: Okay thanks , the course didn't tell us to assume which type it is but if it is impossbile then i must assume  types , and it is solving my problem.

Comment: @Michael Walz well this is the full breif :/**
 * brief Allocate memory for an object which contain duplication of the given key.
 * If run out of memory, free all the memory that was already allocated by the function, 
 * report error MEM_OUT to the standard error and return NULL.
 */         the final part wasn't needed for the question so i removed him..

Comment: That brief is out of context, at least for me. A "key" can be anything, often it's a string, or an `int`. Closing as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: Is `CloneKeyFcn` signature that takes only `void*` forced onto you or rather is `AddKeyValue` (or whatever it is called) signature is forced to take just `void*` for key? If so, you are out of luck. But if you can change it, nothing stops you from getting data size as well.

Comment: I tried to write an answer, passing in a pointer to a function that clones the key. But that is not enough. In a hash table, you have to know how to generate the hash code, compare keys for equality and deallocate them. None of this is possible with bare void pointers. Can you post some more context please..

Comment: @JeremyP Yes i asked the course staff after realizing is it impossible with out knowing which type and they confirmed that it is either int or str void pointers..

Comment: @DavidPitts well that didn't really help either. You now know you're getting a pointer to either ''int'' *or* ''string''. Whatever you choose you're risking getting it wrong and getting undefined behaviour, possibly segfaults. Unless there is some kind of weird restriction that your strings are always one byte shorter than ''sizeof(int)'' plus binary zero and some other magic around it.

Comment: @DavidPitts If you have a void pointer and you know that it points either to a string or to an `int` you still cannot know if the pointer points to an `int` or to a string. It's like if I give you a box telling you that there is either an apple or a pear in it. You cannot know what is in the box.

Comment: @DavidPitts if you find a solution or the if the course staff finally reveals the solution, please post it here, I'd be curious. But I'm sure you're not telling us everything.